# Junk characters "&amp;#7;" are added and stopping application tool tip functionality to work

Tags: java

Tool tip- functionality is working fine for 1 object but when more object get add at that time it fails.

In `catalina.out` objects are displayed with no junk characters but when I look in UI via f12, I can see junk character `"&amp;#7;"`.

In java code I used `replaceAll` and `split` but no success.

Code-

```
     sHasCP1+="ISS-0000430&amp;#7;ISS-0000434&amp;#7;ISS-0000435&amp;#7;ISS-0000436";
    //sHasCP1 = sHasCP1.replace("&amp;#7;" , ";");
    //sHasCP1 = sHasCP1.replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9]" , " ");
     String[] seperator = new String[50];
     seperator = sHasCP1.split("&amp;#7;");
     List<String> list = (List) Arrays.asList(seperator);
     StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
     //display elements of List
     System.out.println("String array converted to List");
     for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
         name.append(list.get(i));

          if ( i != list.size()-1){

             name.append(", ");

         }

         System.out.println(name.toString());
     }
```

and I am passing name value in title -

```
 sbOut.append("<img src=\"..conCP.gif\" border=\"0\" title=\""+name+ "\"/>");
```

Comment: `&#7;` is the HTML entitiy for Ctrl-G aka ASCII BEL control character, historically used to beep (bell). And additonally `&` was encoded as entity `&amp;`. Maybe a BEL char, `u0007`, was initially added in the string. Maybe TAB was intended. **For regex: `split("\\&amp;#7;"`.**

Comment: Please can you elaborate, how can i get rid of this characters?

Comment: So you know, defining a blank `String[]` is useless. You're just tossing it away when you reassign the variable to another chunk of memory -- the one returned by `split(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing where and when the HTML entity is introduced; the following should do:

```
final String REPLACEMENT = "\t"; // Or ""?
sHasCP1 = sHasCP1.replace("&amp;#7;", REPLACEMENT);
sHasCP1 = sHasCP1.replace("&#7;", REPLACEMENT);
sHasCP1 = sHasCP1.replace("\u0007", REPLACEMENT);
```

In a first version I leave a TAB character instead. `", "` or so would do too.

Nicer would be to inspect/debug/log the exact string.